# Parse contents within the HTML tag in iphone

Tags: html, iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am loading,html contents to list in the UILabel.I was able to remove the tags and append the contents.The problem is there are certain cases where content like

Is it y=2 or x>2

,y<1 Hello  x = 2,World!!,what i get after stripping is like "Is it y=2 or x ","y".Is there a way to get the contents fully.I used "NSString+Html" category for stripping the html contents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `&lt;` or `&gt;`